# Google Apps Script to search and extract email addresses from email body and save to spreadshet

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Is it possible to search a Gmail mailbox for a specific label/and or subject and extract email  addresses from email body and save to a spreadsheet?

Email body example:

CEP  11.900-000

UF   sp

Telefone     (13)-3921-6641

Cel  (13)997669994

E-Mail  test.test@gmail.com

Banco    cicred

Many Thanks,
Rod

Comment: You could do that with JS string manipulation without too much efforts but it will never be perfectly foolproof (for example if you have more than one email adresses in the same body...) see the docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) for example

Comment: You can copy this Google Sheet to [extract email addresses](http://www.labnol.org/internet/extract-gmail-addresses/28037/) from Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something around this code, that will return comma separated emails found within StrObj:

```
function findEmailAddresses(StrObj) {
  var separateEmailsBy = ", ";
  var email = ""; // if no match, use this
  var emailsArray = StrObj.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
  if (emailsArray) {
    email = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < emailsArray.length; i++) {
      if (i != 0) email += separateEmailsBy;
      email += emailsArray[i];
    }
  }
  return email;
}
```